# How to show a widget while a asyncronous task is executing and then show a done widget after it has executed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I wanted to make a asynchronous loading dialog, that retrieves data from a database(this is the asynchronous task) and once it is done, i want to show a dialog box that shows the data retrieved.
Meaning, I want to show a loading dialog box widget while the data is being retrieved from the database, and once the data is retrieved, show it on the screen using a dialog box

Comment: use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) then

Comment: but how can i do it if the future func is called on a button click @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this we need to handle tree scenario,

- Before data call, show nothing
- on future call, show progressBar
- after fetch, use data

Using two nullable variable to handle this situation

Simply replace the widget according to your need.

```dart
class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  Future<int> fecthData() async {
    return Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
    ).then(
      (value) => 4,
    );
  }

  bool? _isLoading;
  int? data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = true; //set true while fetching
                  });
                  data = await fecthData();
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = false; //set false while fetching
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Fetch")),
            if (_isLoading == true) CircularProgressIndicator(),
            if (data != null) Text("${data!}") // if you have data show it
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```